# creating a column that describes missing values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datafram as follows:

```
A,B,C,D
Nan,NaN,NaN,NaN
Nan,b,c,NaN
Nan,2,Nan,d
a,e,NaN,f
i,j,1,NaN
```

I want to create a column E that describes missing pattern in other columns for example:
column E would contain something like

```
A,B,C,D,E
Nan,NaN,NaN,NaN,ABCD
Nan,1,2,NaN,AD
Nan,3,Nan,d,AC
a,e,NaN,6,C
i,j,4,5,
```

I tried `df.isnull().sum(axis=1)`
but this doesn't consider order for example in row 4 and 5 , it returns the same value 1. 
How can I create a column like I want as mentioned above?

Comment: What do you need this column for? There might be a better way.

Comment: I need the column to know which values are missing. Using method above return empty string when none of the columns have NaN. How can I go around it? May be 'not missing' in column E when no missing vlaues.

Comment: _I need the column to know which values are missing._ Know how, in what way, what for? Just by looking at the data you know which values are missing, right, so is that it?

Comment: yes, just want to know which columns have missing values

Comment: Any amount of missing values? What are you doing with that information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way sing [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
df['E'] = df.isna().dot(df.columns)

print(df)

    A    B    C    D     E
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ABCD
1  NaN    b    c  NaN    AD
2  NaN    2  NaN    d    AC
3    a    e  NaN    f     C
4    i    j    1  NaN     D
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC we can just `map` and `agg`

```
df["null"] = (
    df.isnull()
    .apply(lambda x: x.map({True: x.name}))
    .stack(0)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg("".join)
)
```

---

```
print(df)

     A    B    C    D  null
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ABCD
1  NaN    b    c  NaN    AD
2  NaN    2  NaN    d    AC
3    a    e  NaN    f     C
4    i    j    1  NaN     D
```